# How to communicate between locally running web services

Tags: node.js, spring, http, localhost, spring-rest

I have some back-end services which can be called only through an API Gateway server. the back-end services are in Spring rest service and API GateWay is a Node Server .these  two servers are running locally on different ports(backend:8080 , node :3000).

How can i make a request to back-end service from my node Server ?

Answer (score 0):

If they both expose rest API you can make use of the inbuilt- http module for communication

```
    require('http');
        var options = {
      host: 'www.google.com',
      port: 80,
      path: '/index.html'
    };

    http.get(options, function(res) {
      console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

      res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
      });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
```

But i would recommend using libraries like [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) or [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

Comment: Am not able to communicate between the local API 's , any idea on how to archive that?